# Annotation with custom types derived from numerical types in Python

Tags: python, class, types, typing

I am trying to create a custom type/class in Python that plays well with annotations and also can be checked in runtime.

The only way I was able to achieve this is by using `TypeAlias`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing

FloatAlias: typing.TypeAlias = float

class FloatClass(float):
    pass

FloatNT = typing.NewType("FloatNT", float)

class AClass:

    a: FloatAlias = 1.23
    b: FloatClass = 1.23 # mypy complains
    c: FloatNT = 1.23    # mypy complains

# True
print(isinstance(3.4, FloatAlias))

# False
print(isinstance(3.4, FloatClass))

# TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
print(isinstance(3.4, FloatNT))
```

But the problem that in certain cases it is resolved back to float and I want to keep track the the user flag it with the custom class, and not with float. Is would rather have something like `FloatClass` or `FloatNT`. Is that possible?

**EDIT**

These new types are aim to provide additional context about the purpose or role of a user defined attribute. I would argue that if a user writes something like this the intent is clear:

```py
class AClass:

    data1: MyFloat = 1.23
    data2: float = 4.56
```

- `MyFloat` is just a thin layer over float
- a Literal is being used

Therefore it would be nice to auto cast it.

However if then there is a function like this:

```py
def do_something(x: MyFloat):
    # code
```

mypy should accept using `data1` but not `data2`.

Comment: `3.4` is a literal `float`, if you want a `FloatClass` instance, you will need to construct one manaully, i.e. `isinstance(FloatClass(3.4), FloatClass)` will evaluate to `True`. `b: FloatClass = FloatClass(1.23)` will work like you expected (and mypy will not find issues with that).  I am assuming you want your user to use your custom `float` subclass, it isn't exactly clear as to why you want to do what you are doing yet.

Comment: What is your actual goal in creating a "custom type"?  Do you want to extend the functionality of the base type?  Keep exactly the same functionality but narrow the acceptable values?  Either a subclass or a `NewType` would probably be the way to go, depending, but in either case you need to explicitly initialize an object as that type (in the case of the subclass that's needed in order to initialize your custom functionality, and in the case of `NewType` the fact that you need to explicitly declare it is basically the entire point).

Comment: @Samwise @metatoaster: the goal is to provide addional information about purpose within the type. However, I would like to avoid writing  `FloatClass(1.23)` or `FloatNT(1.23)` that is unnecesary from the API point of view.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `NewType` then -- if you want to provide additional information about purpose within the type, you do that by saying `FloatNT(1.23)` rather than `1.23`.  The `FloatNT()` part is how you express that a given value is a `FloatNT` rather than a regular `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want is the `NewType` option, which does require that you explicitly initialize the values as the more specific type in order for mypy to accept them being assigned to variables of that type.

```
FloatNT = typing.NewType("FloatNT", float)

class AClass:
    c: FloatNT = FloatNT(1.23)
```

You might argue that if you say:

```
class AClass:
    data1: FloatNT = 1.23  # error!
    data2: float = 4.56
```

the intent is clear and so the type should automatically convert, but mypy does not automatically "convert" a less specific type to a more specific type, any more than it'll automatically convert a type if you do something like:

```
class AClass:
    data1: bool = 1  # error!
    data2: bool = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still think it would be nice to to have a way to "register" a custom numerical type. I do understant why it does not automatically convert, but I would argue it is not the same to cast a Literal than a variable. In the first the intent is quite clear, the second might indicate that there is a problem with the logic of the code.

Comment: In cases where I've used `NewType` it's been to enforce some kind of validation (usually around strings that need to be constrained in certain ways), and in those cases being able to assign literals to a variable with the more narrow type would make it easy to accidentally circumvent the validation.

Comment: I just realized that somehow `typing.ClassVar` works within a class definition as desired. i.e. `ClassVar[float] = 1.23` does not produce a mypy problem.

Comment: This doesn't work with generics in the general case (e.g. you can't assign `List[float] = 1.23`).  That's because `ClassVar[float]` is still a `float`, it's not a more specific type of float.  All `ClassVar` does is generate an error if you try to set the variable on an instance.

Comment: Yes. Type checkers recognize ClassVar[float] as float. It would be nice to teach them to do the same with custom classes. In the same way you can teach them of your own TypeGuards

Comment: That's essentially a `TypeAlias`.  All of these things have different semantics/uses.  If you wanted to introduce your own kind of type wrapper with its own semantics you can always fork `mypy`, or put together a detailed PEP, or both.  :)

Comment: Not the same as TypeAlias because `get_type_hints` will resolve a TypeAlias to the original types. Writing a PEP would be challenging for me at this stage. The state of python typing is dificult to grasp (and kind of a mess if you ask me). For example, it is hard to use issubclass or isinstance equivalents properly in generic types. Also, generics are confusing the way they are implemented. I hope that https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/ gets approbed soon.